Clearing a list of variables: Problems trying to control the order-of-evaluation
I am having trouble controlling the order of evaluation of mathematica expressions.
What I would really like is a general solution, in the form of a pair of functions OrderedEvaluation[] and Priority[] that would allow full control of the order of evaluation as in the following example:
OrderedEvaluation[Priority[f,1][Priority[g,2][Priority[x,3]]]]

which would return f[g[x]] evaluated in the reverse of the standard order with f evaluated first, g evaluated second, and x evaluated last.  Similarly, if I wanted x to evaluate first, then f, then g, I would use
OrderedEvaluation[Priority[f,2][Priority[g,3][Priority[x,1]]]]
What most recently prompted frustration with this recurring problem was an attempt to clear every variable in a list of variables, only to be frustrated by Mathematica replacing every variable in the list by its numerical values, and then attempting to apply Clear to the actual numerical values!  Specifically, when I try
Clear[variables, x, y]; 
variables = {x, y}; 
{x, y} = {1, 1}; 
Clear@@variables; 
x

the output is 1, instead of x.  Nothing changes when I replace Clear@@variables by Clear[variables] or Clear/@variables, because variables is replaced by {1,1} beforeClearsees it, even though Definition[variables] shows that indeed that variables is defined as {x,y}, not {1,1}.
I am aware that in this simple example Clear[x,y] would do the trick, but more generally I want to understand why I am unable to control Mathematica's order of execution.
Here are all the things I have tried.  In each case, Mathematica outputs 1, meaning the variable x has not been cleared.  (The desired output is x.) Sometimes error messages are also generated, but I haven't shown those:
Clear[variables, x, y]; 
variables = {x, y}; 
{x, y} = {1, 1}; 
Clear[variables]; 
x

and
Clear[variables, x, y]; 
variables = {x, y}; 
{x, y} = {1, 1}; 
Clear @@ variables; 
x

and
Clear[variables, x, y]; 
variables = {x, y}; 
{x, y} = {1, 1}; 
Clear /@ variables; 
x 

and
Clear[variables, x, y, ClearList]; 
variables = {x, y};
ClearList = Clear;
SetAttributes[ClearList, {Listable, HoldAll}]; 
{x, y} = {1, 1}; 
Clearlist[variables];
x  

and
Clear[variables, x, y, ClearList];
variables = {x, y};
ClearList = Clear;
SetAttributes[ClearList, {Listable, HoldAll}]; 
{x, y} = {1,1}; 
Clearlist @@ variables; 
x 

and
Clear[variables, x, y, ClearList];
variables = {x, y};
ClearList = Clear;
SetAttributes[ClearList, {Listable, HoldAll}]; {x, y} = {1,1}; 
Clearlist /@ variables; 
x    

and
Clear[variables, x, y, Clearlist2];
SetAttributes[ClearList2, {Listable, HoldAllComplete}];
ClearList = Clear;
variables = {x, y}; {x, y} = {1, 1}; 
Clearlist2 /@ variables; 
x    

and
Clear[variables, x, y, Clearlist2];
ClearList2 = Clear;
SetAttributes[ClearList2, {Listable, HoldAllComplete}];
variables = {x, y}; 
{x, y} = {1, 1}; 
Clearlist2[variables]; 
x    

and
Clear[variables, x, y, Clearlist2];
ClearList2 = Clear;
SetAttributes[ClearList2, {Listable, HoldAllComplete}];
variables = {x, y}; 
{x, y} = {1, 1}; 
Clearlist2 @@ variables; 
x    

and
SetAttributes[DelayedApply, {HoldAllComplete}]; 
DelayedApply = Apply;
Clear[variables, x, y, Clearlist2];
ClearList2 = Clear;
SetAttributes[ClearList2, {Listable, HoldAllComplete}];
variables = {x, y}; 
{x, y} = {1, 1}; 
DelayedApply[Clearlist2, variables];
x

Any help would be much appreciated!

Frame challenge: use replacement rules {x -> a, y -> b} instead of assigning values to variables.  This of course depends on the computational context. Replacements are longer computationally, but if your code requires you to clear variables, that's also likely to take a long time computationally, and likely you should change the approach. It's an interesting question about evaluation control, though.

I am more interested in controlling the order of execution of mathematica commands in general, much more so than finding work-arounds in this specific example.   The problem is that Clear[variables] first evaluates variables (by replacing x and y with their own values) and then evaluates Clear[].  I want to force the order of evaluation to be reversed, so that Clear will operate on the variables x and y themselves, rather than on the numbers stored in the variables.  Attempts to define a new version of Clear with the HoldAll or HoldAllComplete attributes didn't work.

“I want to force the order of evaluation to be reversed, so that Clear will operate on the variables x and y themselves, rather than on the numbers stored in the variables. ” I'm afraid you've misunderstood something. What you're describing is not a reverse. Just observe Clear[variables, x, y]; variables = {x, y}; {x, y} = {1, 1}; Trace[Clear @@ variables]  and think about what's happening here.

I tried the top solution in your link  "How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?" but Step[Clear@@variables] and Step[Clear/@variables] didn't solve the problem.

You need to add @xzczd in your comment, otherwise I won't get the reminder. Then, you still don't understand the issue: Clear @@ step[variables]

Notice I'm using the new syntax of Clear introduced in 13.2. If you're in earlier version, try e.g. Clear @@@ step[variables] // ReleaseHold.

You have a misunderstanding what is stored in a variable. Please read the help about "OwnValue".
As an example, lets look at your first example:
variables = {x, y};

What is stored in "variables"? This can be seen by:
OwnValues[variables]

{HoldPattern[variables] :> {x, y}}

If you now define:
{x, y} = {1, 1};

this stores OwnValues for x and y. However, it does not change "variables":
OwnValues[variables]

{HoldPattern[variables] :> {x, y}}

"variables" is unchanged. When you now clear "variables" your clear the above OwnValues of "variables"and not x or y. x and y are not touched by it.:
Clear[variables];
OwnValues[variables]

{}

And:
OwnValues[x]

1

And:
OwnValues[y]

1


What follows is not really a recommendation--I suspect there is some better way to handle your "real" situation--but maybe it'll suffice to explain how to control evaluation order.
What I think you're trying to do is to create a list of variables that you want to clear, presumably because it's easier to create this list rather than do something like Clear[x, y, z, ...] for a long list.
Problem #1
You need to be careful exactly how you construct your list. If you do something like this:
x = 1;
y = 2;
vars = {x, y};

Then you're out of luck. The rule defining vars knows nothing about x and y, because {x, y} was evaluated before Set. Based on your examples, I think you already know this, but I call it out just in case. You have two options. Either define vars before the other symbols or use SetDelayed. Let's assume you use SetDelayed.
Problem #2
We need to define ClearList in such a way that it works for a list but doesn't operate on the result of evaluating the list. Here's a full version, but there might be more clever ways.
SetAttributes[ClearList, {HoldAll}];
ClearList[vars_Symbol] :=                        (* #1 *)
  If[
    ValueQ[vars, Method -> "OwnValuesPresent"],    (* #2 *)
    MapAt[Clear, OwnValues[vars], {1, 2}][[1, 2]], (* #3 *)
    "handle the input error here"]

We need to define this for a symbol (see #1), because if you were able to pass in an explicit list, then you wouldn't need to do any of this at all--you'd just pass that list to Clear and be done with it. That type check isn't strictly needed, but it helps us clarify the usage.
In #2, vars gets passed to ValueQ after being replaced by the actual input--that's just how the evaluation engine works. ValueQ has the HoldAll attribute, so whatever was bound to vars doesn't get fully evaluated, and instead we determine whether the passed symbol has OwnValues.
If it does have OwnValues (#3), then we fetch the OwnValues. Now, elements of OwnValues will be RuleDelayed expressions, so the right hand sides (the "definitions") will be held. That means we can play with that expression as long as we're careful not to trigger evaluation of the symbols we're trying to clear. Let's go ahead and map Clear to the right hand side, and we end up with a slightly modified RuleDelayed expression. The Clear doesn't actually evaluate, though, because the RuleDelayed is still holding the right hand side. So, let's extract that right hand side, resulting in evaluation, but now Clear is in control and does the right thing.
Side note, the symbol passed in doesn't need to be an actual list, it just needs to be something that has own values that contain what we're trying to clear.
Some usage examples:
x = 1;
y = 9;
z := x;
variables := {x, y};
ClearList[variables];
ClearList[z];

Checking...
x
(* x *)

z
(* x *)

Suggested follow up explorations
You should also look into Unevaluated and Hold and related constructs. Slightly different, but you should also look into Inactivate. Play with these for awhile and you'll start to understand how the evaluation engine orders its evaluation and also how you can interrupt that evaluation.
Update to address comments
Let's start with a simple example to illustrate what the Hold* attributes and related evaluation-interrupting symbols actually do.
SetAttributes[testFunction, HoldAll];
testFunction[arg_] := arg

Now,
x = 17;
testFunction[x]
(* 17, not x *)

Let's follow the evaluation:
Trace[testFunction[x]]
(* {testFunction[x],x,17} *)

So, testFunction did indeed return exactly the symbol x. But that's not the end of the evaluation. The evaluation engine now has a new expression to work with, namely x, and it finds a replacement rule for that x, applies the rule, and we end up with 17.
Let's try a naive approach to handling the "raw" argument:
SetAttributes[testFunction2, HoldAll];
testFunction2[arg_] := SymbolName[arg];
x = 17;
testFunction2[x]
(* SymbolName[17] along with a warning message *)

Again, let's inspect the evaluation sequence:
Trace[testFunction2[x]]
(* {testFunction2[x],SymbolName[x],{x,17},SymbolName[17],... ,SymbolName[17]} *)

Again, we see that our function did keep the argument held unevaluated, but the result was a new expression with a x in it, and the evaluation engine keeps chugging along until it sees no change. So, how do we "capture" that raw argument and do something with it "before" it evaluates?
SetAttributes[testFunction3, HoldAll];
testFunction3[arg_] := SymbolName[Unevaluated[arg]];
x = 17;
testFunction3[x]
(* "x" *)

Or, we could have passed it to something that would hold it.
SetAttributes[{testFunction4, testFunction5}, HoldAll];
testFunction4[arg_] := testFunction5[arg];
x = 17;
testFunction4[x]
(* testFunction5[x] *)

In this case, since testFunction5 had no replacement rules, it just evaluates to itself, holding the argument as per its attributes.
Or check this out:
SetAttributes[testFunction6, HoldAll];
testFunction6[arg_] := Unevaluated[arg] /. {x -> z};
x = 17;
y = 18;
z = 19;
testFunction6[{x, y}]
(* {17, 18} *)

That's not what I wanted! The rule {x -> z} was evaluated to be {17 -> 19}, and 17 wasn't found in {x, y}, so no replacement happened. The function returned {x, y} which then was evaluated to {17, 18}. What we should have done is this:
SetAttributes[testFunction7, HoldAll];
testFunction7[arg_] := Unevaluated[arg] /. {HoldPattern[x] -> z};
x = 17;
y = 18;
z = 19;
testFunction7[{x, y}]
(* {19, 18} *)

And it goes on and on.

I was aware of problem #1.  (Indeed, in each example attempt I was careful to define the list of variables before assigning their values.)
The solution in section "Problem #2" is nice, but I wonder if there is a way to solve the more general issue I have (not just when using Clear[]) to force mathematica to evaluate the outer expression before the inner one.  In this case, Mathematica evaluates Clear[variables] first by evaluating variables (replacing them by their assignments) and then evaluating Clear[], despite attempts to use the HoldAll and HoldAllComplete assignments.

I'm not sure what you're referring to, but when Mathematica evaluates Clear[variables] it does NOT first evaluate variables. That would defeat the whole purpose of Clear. Clear holds its arguments unevaluated precisely so it can inspect them as symbols rather than as what they would evaluate to after applying replacement rules. So, Clear[variables] removes the replacement rules attached to variables. It does nothing with whatever symbols might appear in the right hand side of variables's replacement rules.

Mathematica's evaluation process is actually fairly well documented: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html . I don't know what you consider to be the "inner" or "outer" expression, but if you provide a clear example of what you consider to be the "more general issue" then maybe we can help you figure out how to control the evaluation.

I'm reading your comment again, and the only thing that I can figure is that you somehow think that attributes like HoldAll are sort of permanent in their effect. They aren't. As soon as you reference one of the held arguments in the body of your function, that argument will be evaluated unless you do something to prevent that. Maybe I'll update my answer....

Sorry, I meant to say mathematica evaluates variables first when I try Clear@@variables or Clear/@variables.   I want it to evaluate Clear first, without replacing the variables by their assignments.

Thanks for your long reply.  However, I directly cut and paste your code #2 and your usage example into my browser, but it did not work in Mathematica 11.2.  After removing Method -> OwnValues, which is not supported in Mathematica 11.2,  your usage example generates the error "Clear::ssym: {x,y} is not a symbol or a string."   I tried futzing with your code to get Clear to act directly on the elements of {x,y}, instead of on the list itself, but I didn't get it to work, and I had the original problem that Clear[] tries to clear the values of x,y  instead of the variables x,y.

Okay, sorry, I'm using version 14 and don't know how to make the solution compatible with version 11. But you're probably going to need to do something along the lines I showed you. I think you're still not completely understanding the problem, though. You said you wanted to understand the order of evaluation, but then you keep making incorrect assertions about the order of evaluation, so you seem to be stubbornly refusing to listen to what all of us are trying to tell you. Briefly put, you're going to need to figure out how to inspect variables without evaluating `variables.

Honestly, I tried your code and it doesn't work, so I don't how you come out with accusation that I'm not listening.   What is incorrect about saying that Mathematica is evaluating the variables (meaning replacing them by their values) before invoking Clear[]????   I know how to make Clear work on a list now, but converting the definition to a string, but that still doesn't solve the more general problem of not being able to control the order in which rules are implemented by the evaluation engine.

I'm going to vote to close this question, but if you want to understand what I'm trying to tell you, I'll summarize here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152885/clearing-a-list-of-variables

Here is some code that works on the specific problem of clearing the variables in a given list of variables, but it isn't a general solution of the type I want because it is by-hand and not a general solution for forcing mathematica's evaluation engine to reorder its application of transformation rules used to evaluate expressions.
It would be nice if Mathematica had a graphical interface that would show the TreeForm of an expression and allow you to assign a desired order of evaluation.
Clear[ClearList];  (*If the argument of ClearList is a variable 
containing a List of variables, then clear all the variables in the list*)
SetAttributes[ClearList, HoldAll];
ClearList::BadInput = "Argument of ClearList[] is not a variable containing a list"; 
ClearList[vars_Symbol] := 
 Module[{stringdef, pattern},
  stringdef = ToString[Definition[vars]];   (*To prevent the variables in the
    list from being evaluated, write the definition of the list to a string*)
  pattern = ToString[Unevaluated[vars]] ~~ " = {" ~~ x___ ~~ "}";   
    (*This pattern is vars = {list of stuff}.*)
  If[TrueQ[StringMatchQ[stringdef, pattern]],
  ToExpression[StringReplace[stringdef, pattern :> "Clear[" ~~ x ~~ "]"]], 
  Message[ClearList::BadInput]]
 ]

Running the code gives:
Input: Clear[variables, x, y]; variables = {x, y}; {x, y} = {1, 1}; ClearList[vars]; {vars, x, y}

Output: {{x, y}, x, y}

